# How to get a scatter matrix consisting of just scatterplots with a 1:1 line, and good axis labels?

Tags: r, ggpairs, scatter-matrix

I want to have a matrix of just scatterplots in which a 1:1 line is present.
The data has the following structure:

```
bulk_SIC_25 <- data.frame(soilsample$bulk_SIC_scheibler_25,soilsample$bulk_SIC_LECO.CBLB_25,soilsample$bulk_SIC_RE6_25)
colnames(bulk_SIC_25)<-c("SIC_scheibler_25","SIC_LECO-CBLB_25","SIC_RE6_25")
```

The data inside the dataframe is:

> > dput(bulk_SIC_25)
> > structure(list(SIC_scheibler_25 = c(8.292, 9.648, 9.072, 6.084,
> > 10.944, 12.48, 4.368, 6.732, 5.592, 9.024, 8.7, 9.48, 9.588,
> > 3.432, NA, 15.72), `SIC_LECO-CBLB_25` = c(6.9, 9.5, 8, 6.6, 11.1,
> > 13, NA, 7, 5.5, 8.95, 9.14, 9.6, 9.2, 3.5, NA, NA), SIC_RE6_25 = c(10.4,
> > 10.7, 11.3, 8.6, 13.2, 15.5, 6.3, 9.6, 7.6, 10.5, 10.7, 11.3,
> > 11.4, 5.1, 17.2, 17.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
> > -16L))

The pairs function produces a nice matrix with just scatterplots and visible x/y axes and variable names:
[example pairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsgVh.png)

```r
pairs(bulk_SIC_25, labels=colnames(bulk_SIC_25),gap=0.5, main=" Total Carbon in bulk soil ",lower.panel=NULL, cex.labels=1.5 ,pch=21, bg="Black")`
```

However, I cannot change the size of the points, nor add a 1:1 line.
Therefore, I switched to ggpairs with internal labels:

[Example ggpairs internal labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UVbE.png)
Code:

```r
ggpairs(data=soilsample, columns = c("bulk_SIC_scheibler_25","bulk_SIC_LECO.CBLB_25","bulk_SIC_RE6_25"), upper="blank",axisLabels = "internal")+ggtitle(label="Soil Organic Carbon bulk soil")+theme_bw(base_size=15)+geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)+labs(x="g C/ kg soil", y= "g C / kg soil")+geom_point(size=3)+  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

However, as you can see, the gridlines of the internal axislabels do not match with the scatterplots, so that the scatterplots are very hard to read.

I have tried:

```r
limitRangediag <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
      ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + 
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5, 16)) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(5, 16)) 
}

ggpairs(data=soilsample, columns = c("bulk_SIC_scheibler_25","bulk_SIC_LECO.CBLB_25","bulk_SIC_RE6_25"), upper="blank",lower = list(continuous = limitRange),diag=list(continous=limitRangediag),axisLabels = "internal")+ggtitle(label="Soil Organic Carbon bulk soil")+theme_bw(base_size=15)+geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)+labs(x="g C/ kg soil", y= "g C / kg soil")+geom_point(size=3)+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I know I do something wrong in writing the function, but I am very inexperienced in this and no clue what I do wrong.

I could also have peace in putting external labels on the right spot in ggpairs (so skipping the first blank row, and put the labels above the plots itself), but I would have no clue to do this...:
[example ggpairs external labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbG69.png)

```r
ggpairs(data=df, columns = c("bulk_SIC_scheibler_25","bulk_SIC_LECO.CBLB_25","bulk_SIC_RE6_25"), upper="blank",diag="blank",axisLabels = "shown")+ggtitle(label="Soil Organic Carbon bulk soil")+theme_bw(base_size=15)+geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)+labs(x="g C/ kg soil", y= "g C / kg soil")+geom_point(size=3)+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

If anybody could help me out in fixing one of these 3 options to get a nice matrix of scatterplots with a 1:1 line and points adjustable in size, with readable axis labels, I would be very grateful!!

Comment: use `dput()` to show a piece of your data. I think no one could comment without see that.

Comment: Good point! I am obviously a  new-bie here ;-) I will update my post with this information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in `pairs()`, you can specify the `panel=` argument (which is `points()` by default) as a function that includes whatever you want, such as a call to `abline()` (in your case you would use `upper.panel=`, since you want the lower panel to be NULL)
- the `cex` argument (which is passed to the panel function) will change the point size.

```r
pairs(mtcars[,1:5],
   panel = function(...) { points(...); abline(a=0,b=1,lty=2,col="red") },
   cex=4,
   gap=0  ## you didn't ask for this but I prefer it
)
```

In this particular example the 1:1 line doesn't appear in every panel, but it's there in principle (you'd have to set x, y limits to ensure that it intersected with the panel area)

[image]

Comment: This suggestion works perfectly, thank you so much!!